# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, parameters

Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

I have a following function which throws the above error. I am handling all nulls in store procedure and in the C# code.

So where is it getting this error?

I can see the error in the catch block. But i am not understanding which line in the following create() getting the error.

```
public Boolean Create(DataTO DataTO)
{
    IDbTrans transaction = null;
    IDbCmd IDbCmd;

    string EncryptedPassword = Encrypt(DataTO.txtPwd);
    Base dataAccCom = null;

    try
    {
        dataAccCom = Factory.Create();
        dataAccCom.OpenConnection();
        transaction = dataAccCom.BeginTransaction();
        IDbCmd = dataAccCom.CreateCommand("sp_Register", true);
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "op_Id", DbType.Int64, 0, ParameterDirection.Output);
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_dlstTitle", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(DataTO.dlstTitle));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtFirstName", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(DataTO.txtFirstName));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtMiddleName", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(DataTO.txtMiddleName));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtLastName", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(DataTO.txtLastName));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtDob", DbType.DateTime, DataTO.txtDob);
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtDesig", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(DataTO.txtDesig));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtOFlatNo", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(DataTO.txtOFlatNo));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtOBuild", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(DataTO.txtOBuild));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtOPost", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(DataTO.txtOPost));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtOArea", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(DataTO.txtOArea));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtOCity", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(DataTO.txtOCity));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtRBuild", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(DataTO.txtRBuild));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtRPost", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(DataTO.txtRPost));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtUserID", DbType.String,ReplaceNull(DataTO.txtUserID));
        dataAccCom.AddParameter(IDbCmd, "p_txtPwd", DbType.String, ReplaceNull(EncryptedPassword));
        dataAccCom.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCmd);
        DataTO.Id = Convert.ToInt64(dataAccCom.GetParameterValue(IDbCmd, "op_Id"));
        transaction.Commit();
        return true;



    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        if (transaction != null)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        transaction = null;
        if (dataAccCom != null)
        {
            dataAccCom.CloseConnection();
        }
        dataAccCom = null;
        IDbCmd = null;
    }
}

public string ReplaceNull(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public DateTime ReplaceNull(DateTime value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
    else
    {
        return value;
    }
}

public double ReplaceNull(double value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that your `ReplaceNull` overloads on `double` and `DateTime` are worthless. Values of these types can never be null and will therefore never pass the `if (value == null)` condition.

Comment: Unless they're made nullable of course, but that's another story.

Comment: And have you stepped through the method? In Visual Studio, consider breaking on all exceptions (Ctrl+Alt+E) and see what line actually causes the problem.

Comment: ok ..whts the solution for the question :-)

Comment: Whoa, whoa! Don't "throw ex", just "throw" or you will lose some of your trace. That doesn't solve your problem but its a good practice to get in the habit of doing.

Comment: ^^ I am always learning something new. Just when I think I knew what I needed to know about exceptions...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I'm thinking that your output parameter is coming back with a DBNull value. Add a check for that like this

```
var outputParam = dataAccCom.GetParameterValue(IDbCmd, "op_Id");
if(!(outputParam is DBNull))
     DataTO.Id = Convert.ToInt64(outputParam);
```

Comment: Maybe better `Convert.IsDBNull()`?

Comment: I have multiple integer values in my query. Can I somehow shorten the process or I have to do this for everyone?

Comment: @Alexander, I hope you found an answer before now, but it can get pretty ugly to get shorter than this, but using s ternary would work: DataTO.Id = dataAccCom.GetParameterValue(IDbCmd, "op_Id") == DBNull.Value ? null : Convert.ToInt64(dataAccCom.GetParameterValue(IDbCmd, "op_Id"));

Answer (score 18):

I suspect that the line

```
DataTO.Id = Convert.ToInt64(dataAccCom.GetParameterValue(IDbCmd, "op_Id"));
```

is causing the problem.  Is it possible that the `op_Id` value is being set to null by the stored procedure?

To Guard against it use the `Convert.IsDBNull` method.  For example:

```
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dataAccCom.GetParameterValue(IDbCmd, "op_Id"))
{
 DataTO.Id = Convert.ToInt64(dataAccCom.GetParameterValue(IDbCmd, "op_Id"));
}
else 
{
 DataTO.Id = ...some default value or perform some error case management
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to check for `DBNull`, not `null`. Additionally, two of your three `ReplaceNull` methods don't make sense. `double` and `DateTime` are non-nullable, so checking them for `null` will always be `false`...

Answer (score 5):

Reason for the error: In an object-oriented programming language, null means the absence of a reference to an object. DBNull represents an uninitialized variant or nonexistent database column. Source:MSDN

Actual Code which I faced error:

Before changed the code:

```
    if( ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0] == null ) //   Which is not working

     {
            seqno  = 1; 
      }
    else
    {
          seqno = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]) + 1;
     }
```

After changed the code:

```
   if( ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0] == DBNull.Value ) //which is working properly
        {
                    seqno  = 1; 
         }
            else
            {
                  seqno = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]) + 1;
             }
```

Conclusion: when the database value return the null value, we recommend to use the DBNull class instead of just specifying as a null like in C# language.

Answer (score 4):

TryParse is usually the most elegant way to handle this type of thing:

```
long temp = 0;
if (Int64.TryParse(dataAccCom.GetParameterValue(IDbCmd, "op_Id").ToString(), out temp))
{
   DataTO.Id = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's also worked for me:

- reservation.IsFull = rdr["isfull"] is DBNull ? false : (bool)rdr["isfull"];

Answer (score 0):

For others that arrive on this page from google:

DataRow also has a function `.IsNull("ColumnName")`

```
    public DateTime? TestDt; 
    public Parse(DataRow row)
    {
        if (!row.IsNull("TEST_DT"))
            TestDt = Convert.ToDateTime(row["TEST_DT"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem today and resolved it by checking the mapping class. I had a class which had 5 properties to which 5 columns returned from stored procedure were being mapped. Those properties were non-nullable and due to which i was getting the error. I made them nullable and the issue resolved.

```
    public int? Pause { get; set; }
    public int? Delay { get; set; }
    public int? Transition { get; set; }
    public int? TransitionTime { get; set; }
    public int? TransitionResolution { get; set; }
```

Added "?" with data type to made them nullable.

Secondly i also added isNull check in the stored procedure as well as follows:

```
    isnull(co_pivot.Pause, 0) as Pause,
    isnull(co_pivot.Delay, 0) as Delay,
    isnull(co_pivot.Transition, 0) as Transition,
    isnull(co_pivot.TransitionTime, 0) as TransitionTime,
    isnull(co_pivot.TransitionResolution, 0) as TransitionResolution
```

Hope this helps someone.