# The Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

```
List<exchange_rates> exch_rate_list = new List<exchange_rates>();

foreach (DataRow dr in ExchangeRates.Rows) 
{
    exch_rate_list.Add(new exchange_rates {
        one_usd_to_currency = Convert.ToDouble(dr["one_usd_to_currency"]),
        currency =   dr["currency"].ToString(),                       
    });
}
```

Well I am getting a error saying Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types at this point  `one_usd_to_currency = Convert.ToDouble(dr["one_usd_to_currency"])`, can someone please guide me on this bug, where i have tried many ways of handling by changing Data Types , i do really appreciate if you could guide me on this bug in order to solve this conflict , many thanks !

Comment: Check that `dr["one_usd_to_currency"] != DBNull.Value` before converting it. This is basically the same as a regular NullReferenceException

Comment: You can fix your problem really easy using debug, check how to use it. It will help you in the future !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098646/object-cannot-be-cast-from-dbnull-to-other-types)

Answer (score 2):

When you get `DBNull` as result you have to use this code as `DBNull` is an own type that cannot be cast to anything different `System.Object`:

```
var dbValue = dr["one_usd_to_currency"];
if(dbValue != DBNull.Value) one_usd_to_currency = Convert.ToDouble(dbValue);
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much ! this line of code helps me to fix this conflict very easily , Many thanks !

Answer (score -1):

You can try like....

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ExchangeRates.Rows) {

    if (dr["one_usd_to_currency"] == null)
        dr["one_usd_to_currency"] = 0;

    exch_rate_list.Add(new exchange_rates {
        one_usd_to_currency = Convert.ToDouble(dr["one_usd_to_currency"]),
        currency =   dr["currency"].ToString(),
    });
}
```