# How to handle DBNull exception for multiple values

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net

I am assigning values to a model. Some of these values can be null. I have tried several methods to handle DBNull values but still getting errors

```
 dPbtbud.Xfer = dataFromFile.Tables[0].Rows[i][j++] == DBNull.Value ? 
      0.0 : 
      Convert.ToDouble(dataFromFile.Tables[0].Rows[i][j++]);
```

Also tried

```
 dPbtbud.Xfer = dataFromFile.Tables[0].Rows[i][j++] is DBNull ? 
     0.0 : 
     Convert.ToDouble(dataFromFile.Tables[0].Rows[i][j++]);
```

Non seem to handle null values

Comment: Have you tried: `dataFromFile.Tables[0].Rows[i][j++] == null`?

Comment: @Stefan Yeah just tried. Getting same error "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"

Comment: Where is this data coming from? It looks like it has been read from a file. Is it string data? Than it should be `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataFromFile.Tables[0].Rows[i][j++]) ? 0.0 : ..`

Comment: Unless, it's value is actual `"NULL"` or `"NILL"` or something like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098646/object-cannot-be-cast-from-dbnull-to-other-types)

Comment: Tried that as well...Yeah the data is coming from an excel file exported to a dataset

Comment: @Fabio except I have tried that soln in that question as you can see and still having problems

Comment: @Fabio I scaffolded the model from a database, messing with the nullability won't mess with the database?

Comment: @masksoverflow, can you please add to the question what you tried and what "_Non seem to handle null values_" mean in  your tries, what exception you get for example.

Comment: @Fabio nevermind, the property of Xfer is already nullable

Comment: @masksoverflow, if column in database is nullable then should be ok.

Comment: @Fabio I can't do if and else on it. As in if(!(dataFromFile.Tables[0].Rows[i][j++]) is DBNull))                     Because I am doing this for a couple of values and its going to get really ugly

Comment: You realise that the `j++` executes up to twice, right? So when it is not null, you are fetching the next row (which now may be null).

Comment: Since `Xfer` is nullable double, just do `dPbtbud.Xfer = dataFromFile.Tables[0].Rows[i].Field<double?>[j++]`

Comment: @GSerg Yeah I do realize that. But I think you may be right as in its looking for a value that may now be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to create an extension method to check null and DBNull :

```
namespace Helper
{
 public static class ConvertEX1
    {
        public static object IsNull<T>(this object obj, T def) where T : struct
        {
            if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)
                return (T)Convert.ChangeType(def, typeof(T));
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to import the namespace in every `.cs` file you use your function:

```
using Helper;
...


dPbtbud.Xfer = (double)dataFromFile.Tables[0].Rows[i][j++].IsNull(0.0);
```

Comment: This extension is redundant for OP case, `DataRow` already has extension method `.Field<T>` which will return correct type.