# Error! 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.' C# with method sum()

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dndgK.png)

1. Code is error

sum1 = Convert.ToInt32(dtt.Compute("Sum(BIN1)" ,string.Empty));

2. how can I display on Listbox and just show columns name.

Comment: `dtt.Compute("Sum(BIN1)"` is returning `DBNull`. You want to convert that to `int`. There is no meaningful way to do that. What do you want `sum1` to be if the sum is `DBNull`? 0? 44? Something else?

Comment: if(sum1 == 0), I want to remove colunm "BIN1" on datatable.

Comment: To correct this error, please refer to [Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098646/object-cannot-be-cast-from-dbnull-to-other-types)

Answer (score 0):

```
1.public static object DBNullValueorIntIfNotNull(int value)
    {
        object o;
        if (value <= 0)
        {
            o = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            o = value;
        }
        return o;
    }
```

2.if(sum1 == 0) {
columns name .visibale = false;}