# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types : Data Binding

Tags: data-binding, datasource

I am getting this error when dynamically binding my controls onto the dataSource.
(Most answers respond to when using parameters : like this one [Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098646/object-cannot-be-cast-from-dbnull-to-other-types/6098711#6098711) ).
Can we expand for when binding controls?

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the extensions of the "DataBindings.Add" method: therefore this code:

```
            this.chkDispensed.DataBindings.Add("Checked", DT_items, "dispensedItem_bol");
            this.chkDirectionsAuto.DataBindings.Add("Checked", DT_items, "directionsAuto_bol");
```

.. Changes to

```
            bool myDefBool = false;
            this.chkDispensed.DataBindings.Add("Checked", DT_items, "dispensedItem_bol", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, myDefBool);
            this.chkDirectionsAuto.DataBindings.Add("Checked", DT_items, "directionsAuto_bol", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, myDefBool);
```

This takes care of the NULL values from the database. I suppose it MUST be done for ALL controls, any type. Thank you.